# WCF self-hosted service is not accessible remotely in local network

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am currently creating the WCF self-hosted service (hosted in ConsoleApplication). Service contract is quite simple, it contains only two methods. When I host service locally on the local machine, everything works great. When I try to host it to have an access from other machines in local network things get complicated. I have an access via the browser on the all machines - no problem right here. But when I only try to create the client application and invoke some method I get the following exception:

> Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at >http://localhost:9001/ValueDataService that could accept the message. This is >often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if >present, for more details.

Inner exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I feel confused because I can access it remotely via browser typing http://localhost:9001/ValueDataService address. Client application always throws an above exception.

Just to get things simplified: 
To get WCF service visible on the other machine in local network via browser (instead of single localhost machine), the only thing I have to change is add the

```
hostNameComparisonMode="Exact"
```

attribute to the endpoint binding.

**Update:**
and of course change localhost to IP address of host machine.

Service contract looks like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IValuesDataService
{
  [OperationContract]
  int[] GetValues();

  [OperationContract]
  void SetValues(int[] values);
}
```

Console Application Program looks like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost svcHost = null;
        try
        {
            svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ValueDataService.ValueDataService));
            svcHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Value Data Service has been hosted.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            svcHost = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Service can not be started \n\nError Message [" + e.Message + "]");
        }
        if (svcHost != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to close the Service");
            Console.ReadLine();
            svcHost.Close();
            svcHost = null;
        }
    }
```

Host application App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ValueDataService.ValueDataService"     behaviorConfiguration="mathServiceBehave">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9001/ValueDataService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="ValueDataService.IValueDataService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mathServiceBehave">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="bindingName" hostNameComparisonMode="Exact">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
```

and at least Client Application App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="myBinding">
            <security mode="None"/>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9001/ValueDataService"  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ValueDataServiceReference.IValueDataService"/>
    </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webEndpoint">
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me to get this work?

Comment: you can't access it remotely by `localhost`, that's the "local" machine. Change the client's app.config to use the IP of the machine hosting the server application.

Comment: Like if you are hosting the WCF service on your machine you have to change 'localhost' to whatever your internal IP address is.  You do need to keep the port number though (:9001).

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't  write but, of course I use the IP address of the host machine like http://192.168.0.16/ValueDataService

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

So IIS has a annoying binding system that does not convert IP address requests to localhost bindings. Its and unfortunate thing but thats how its request system works. When you run the WCF service in debug it runs an instance of IIS express with a localhost binding. Hence when the request comes through, it doesn't get translated to the binding address the instance is running on.

How to fix this:

1) Start IIS 
2) Host your Developed Application in IIS with the suitable IP address binding

OLD:
In the link : `http://localhost:9001/ValueDataService` replace `localhost` with server's IP address so that the link would look like : `http://192.168.1.5:9001/ValueDataService` goto network and sharing center/use ipconfig to get server machine's IP address.

The reason the localhost link doesn't work is because when the browser reads localhost it resolves it looks at the computers own network interface rather than look outwards.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I just updated my question, of course I change the localhost to the IP address of host machine too. I have also written that I have an access from the others machines but via browser only.

Comment: Long back someone was trying the wrong IP. I think you have to change the default binding, theres probably some stupid IIS middleware that doesn't recognize the localhost binding in the WCF.